# Primefaces datePicker popup dialog doesn't appear in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces version 3.4 and JDK version 1.6  in my project. 
The problem that i am facing is that Primefaces datepicker pop-up dosent appear in Internet Explorer 9.
Following is the style attribute I have added to datepicker component

`style="left:256px;width:100px;position:absolute;"`

The datepicker popup is working fine in chrome but I have to make it work in IE9.

Can anyone sugest a solution for this?

Comment: Check if it is displaying in compatability mode.

Comment: I have added these meta tags in the <head> section of html                 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE9" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=UTF-8" /> still html takes up Browser mode as-IE9 compatible view and document mode as IE7

Comment: Does this work on IE9 http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf